# Is there a utility combining recursive download and timestamp features from wget and the date filtering feature from curl?

Tags: curl, wget, download

I have set up this cron job that works to download everything recursively and does not replace files in the destination directory if they aren't older than that in the site (or different size):

```
* * * * * wget -r -N -c -P /home/user1/ http://SomeURL
```

(The frequency of the cron being called was just set to every minute for my own testing purposes.  I don't plan on running it every minute.)

I would like to know how I could modify this or use some other utility to only download files with a modified date within the last X number of days.  Reason being there are a lot of files in there, we only need the ones X days old or younger, and I'd rather not have it download everything (even if it only would happen the first time).

I have seen that curl has the feature to download something only if it is later than a certain date, but curl downloads can only download more than one file at a time if they follow a very simple pattern (at least that's my understanding).

I've thought about using wget to recursively get a list of files, then perform curl on each, but I could not find a way to get a list from wget command (over http).  Curl has a way to get a list, but it is not recursive.

I'm hoping that there is some other utility that I do not know about that can achieve this task.

Thanks,
Ben